# interface fields inside other interface

Tags: typescript

I have typescript interface:

```
interface SupplierSettings {
    id_supplier_settings?: number;
    is_auto_order: boolean;
    order_cron: string;
    email: string;
    get_next_run_date?: string;
    dont_wait_for_mail_response: boolean;
}
```

In second interface i would like to have fields from `SupplierSettings`,
that should look like this:

```
interface AssignManufacturerToSupplier {
    upsertSupplierSettings: {

        // fields from SupplierSettings 
        id_supplier_settings?: number;
        is_auto_order: boolean;
        order_cron: string;
        email: string;
        get_next_run_date?: string;
        dont_wait_for_mail_response: boolean;
        // end of fields from SupplierSettings 

        suppliers: {
            connect: number;
        }
    };
    assignManufacturerToSupplier: {
        id_product_supplier: string;
        manufacturers: {
            delete?: [number];
            connect?: [number];
        }
    };
}
```

How can i do that?

I try this:

```
interface AssignManufacturerToSupplier {
    upsertSupplierSettings: {
        SupplierSettings;
        suppliers: {
            connect: number;
        }
    };
    assignManufacturerToSupplier: {
        id_product_supplier: string;
        manufacturers: {
            delete?: [number];
            connect?: [number];
        }
    };
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question

```
interface UpsertSupplierSettingsInterface extends SupplierSettings {
  suppliers: {
     connect: number;
  }
 }


interface SupplierSettings {
  id_supplier_settings?: number;
  is_auto_order: boolean;
  order_cron: string;
  email: string;
  get_next_run_date?: string;
  dont_wait_for_mail_response: boolean;
}

interface AssignManufacturerToSupplier {
  upsertSupplierSettings: UpsertSupplierSettingsInterface,
  assignManufacturerToSupplier: {
     id_product_supplier: string;
     manufacturers: {
       delete?: [number];
       connect?: [number];
     }
   };
}
```

What you want to do is extend the interface so you can apply it immediatly